# R: readBin workaround to character limit (10 000 bytes)?

Tags: xml, r, binary, byte, bit

I have a file that consists both of a XML character header and binary data, which is then read using `readBin` in R:

```
zz <- file('myfile', 'rb')

# Read header
x <- readBin(zz, 'character')

# Read binary data
...
```

However, when the header exceeds 10 000 bytes, I get the following:

```
Warning message:
 In readBin(zz, 'character') :
 null terminator not found: breaking string at 10000 bytes
```

I have tried to loop until the string match the end of the header and then concatenate the strings together, but then the XML does not validate as some of the parts has corrupted endings (e.g. `\xa0W\x97^\xff\177` is added in the end).

How should I deal with the `readBin` character limit - are there any simple workarounds?

Any kinds of suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Below follows a reproducible example:

```
url <- 'http://www.enetpulse.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_xml_feed_enetpulse_icehockey.xml'
x <- paste(readLines(url), collapse = '\n')  # more than 10 000 bytes

f <- tempfile()
zz <- file(f, 'wb')
writeBin(x, zz)  # header
writeBin(1:10000, zz)  # data
close(zz)

# readBin
zz <- file(f, 'rb')
y <- readBin(zz, 'character')
# Warning message:
# In readBin(zz, "character") :
#   null terminator not found: breaking string at 10000 bytes
y
# "... participantFK=\"98707\" [\x97^\xff\177"
close(zz)

# readChar
zz <- file(f, 'rb')
readChar(zz, nchars = 999999)
# Error in readChar(zz, nchars = 999999) : 
#   invalid UTF-8 input in readChar()
close(zz)

# readBin-loop
library(XML)
p <- xmlParse(x)  # it works to parse the original xml
zz <- file(f, 'rb')
fun <- function(x) readBin(zz, 'character')
res <- paste(sapply(1:4, fun), collapse = '')
p2 <- xmlParse(res)  # errors!
```

Comment: What ends the header? How are you breaking up the file? I believe `readBin(,"character")` tries to read till a nul byte. Perhaps you want `readChar` instead? Is there anyway to create a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, I think it's ended by a nul byte. It works great when the header is less than the limit. Using `readChar` leads to: `invalid UTF-8 input in readChar()` - which I guess is when it reaches the binary data (I don't know the length of the header to set `nchars`).

Comment: I will try to make up some sample code, to make it reproducible.

Comment: @MrFlick I have now updated the question with some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. This is indeed a messy file format. Here I propose a more traditional old-school style parsing of the file. Basically read everything in as bytes till we find the null terminator. When we do, we take all those bytes, convert to character, then parse. Then in this example, I rewind the read point to the beginning of the binary data and then I can read that as well with the same connection.

Starting right after you write the test file in your sample code above, I begin with

```
block <- 256*4
zz <- file(f, 'rb')
rr <- raw()
found <- 0
while ( found==0 ) {
    r <- readBin(zz, "raw", block)
    if( length(w<-head(which(r==0),1)) ) {
        rr <- c(rr, r[1:(w-1)])
        found <- 1
        seek(zz, -(block-w), origin="current") #rewind
    } else {
        rr <- c(rr, r)
    }
}

library(XML)
p <- xmlParse(rawToChar(rr), asText=TRUE)
dd <- readBin(zz, "integer",10000)
close(zz)
```

And that recovers the XML file in `p` and the list of integers in `dd`.

This was only possible because you made such a nice reproducible example. And it was also very nice to include the code you tried. Cheers.